# How can I specify a PDF file name?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rendered, name

I'm placing a button on a Visualforce page that creates a PDF in the contract object. If I press this button, a PDF will be generated, but if I save it with "Save as", the file name will always be the name of the Visualforce page. How can I set the file name that I want to set in the field of the contract object so that the field is always set when saving with "Save as"?

<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyhtmltag="false" showheader="false" standardController="Contract" extensions="ContractController">

Comment: Linked an answer for you. Summary, use `contentType="application/pdf#desiredFilename.pdf"`. Please let us know if this solves your problem, or if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I enter below. but it does not work. still show visualforce page name for PDF file name. I want to see at pdf file name as Filename_c in Contract object.
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyhtmltag="false" showheader="false" standardController="Contract" extensions="ContractController" contentType="application/pdf#SomeName{!'Contract__r.FileName__c'}.pdf"></apex:page>>